# CUDA mutex synchronization

Tags: cuda, synchronization

I am currently working on a homework from CUDA programming and I found myself force to synchronize all threads in my kernel. I have implemented simple synchronization mechanism as described in [this article](http://eprints.cs.vt.edu/archive/00001087/01/TR_GPU_synchronization.pdf). However I have encountered strange behaviour so I decided to write a test program for this kind of lock:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ int g_mutex = 0;
__device__ void __gpu_sync(int goalVal) {
    int tid_in_block = threadIdx.x * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if(tid_in_block == 0) {
        atomicAdd(&g_mutex, 1);
        while(g_mutex != goalVal) {}
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

__global__ void deadlock(int *out) {
    __gpu_sync(1000);
    *out = 42;
}

int main() {
    int *dev, local;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev, sizeof(int));
    deadlock<<<1,1>>>(dev);
    cudaMemcpy(&local, dev, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("%d\n", local);
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect that this application should never terminate (as the mutex cannot ever reach the value of 1000). However the application runs as if there was no locking involved and immediately prints out 42. Could you please tell me what I am missing? I am running a CC1.3 system (GTX 260), 64bit Windows 7, CUDA 5.5. Compilation was done by `nvcc -arch compute_12 main.cu`.

Thank you!

Comment: The application deadlocks for me.  Are you running on windows or linux?  Which cuda version? What command are you using to compile?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write it. It's 64bit Windows 7 using CUDA toolkit 5.5. I have compiled the application by `nvcc -arch compute_12 main.cu`.

Comment: It also deadlocks for me: Windows 7, CUDA 5.5, GeForce 540M. Why do you use `compute_12` and not `compute_13` if your card is cc 1.3? `compute_13` is defined.

Comment: I am using `compute_12` as it must be possible to run the application on older cards. However it is really strange that it does not deadlock for me (I have also tried to use `compute_13` but it did not help). Do you have an idea why it is not working properly on my system please?

Comment: If you copy the value of `g_mutex` to host memory and print out the value, what do you get?  That might inform the question of what happened inside of your `__gpu_sync()` method.

Comment: There is 1 in the `g_mutex` variable (so the `atomicAdd` operation worked fine, but the loop was ignored).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is optimizing out the code that would deadlock, since from the standpoint of that thread, it serves no purpose (no identifiable state is modified as a result of that code).

If you want to see the code deadlock, add the `-G` switch when you compile (or in visual studio, compile the debug project) which will disable many compiler optimizations.

The reason there is a difference in behavior between your cc1.3 device and what I initially observed (on my cc2.0 device) and what JackOLantern observed on his cc2.1 device is that `nvcc` uses a different device compiler for cc1.x devices as compared to all cc2.x and newer devices, so the exact optimization behavior can be different.

I tried your code on a cc1.3 device (under linux) and was able to reproduce your observation, even with `-arch=sm_13`

The following modifications to your device code will prevent the compiler from optimizing out the while loop (even if you don't specify `-G`):

```
__device__ int __gpu_sync(int goalVal) {
    int test;
    int tid_in_block = threadIdx.x * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if(tid_in_block == 0) {
        atomicAdd(&g_mutex, 1);
        while(g_mutex != goalVal) {test++;}

    }
    __syncthreads();
    return test;
}

__global__ void deadlock(int *out) {
    *out = __gpu_sync(1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The `-G` switch did a trick for me. However the trick with non-empty loop body is not working for me (actually I tried this one unsuccessfully before I asked here). Probably an unnecessary code removal optimization is done?

Comment: What value do you get when you see the print out of the local variable?

Comment: My guess is that you didn't look at all my code.  Probably you still have the line in your kernel setting `out` to 42.  That will defeat my code and allow the compiler in.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried the `-G` switch and was happy. I've tried to write the `__gpu_sync` according to you. If I have not written the result in global memory, it wasn't working. Once I have made a globally visible effect, the code started to work. Thanks! The only pain for me now is that it requires a write to the global memory that would reduce the level of parallelism a bit (but perhaps I should not care about it once I am using this kind of synchronization).

Comment: @RobertCrovella I'm having the same problem, unable to resolve with the above solutions.

Comment: @user916933 I suggest you post a new question with a short, complete, compilable example of the code you are having trouble with, along with your CUDA version, compile command, and the GPU you are using.